# How to find error in C program that multiplies matrixes

Tags: c, matrix, crash, pthreads

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct ags{
    long int **mat1;
    long int **mat2;
    int *semafor;
    int rowsDone;
};

void *thread_multiply(void*);

int main(int args, char** argv){
    int mat1x;
    int mat1y;
    int mat2x;
    int mat2y;
    int threadsAmount;

    printf("Podaj szerokosc pierwszej macierzy: ");
    scanf("%i", &mat1x);
    printf("Podaj wysokosc pierwszej macierzy: ");
    scanf("%i", &mat1y);
    printf("Podaj szerokosc drugiej macierzy: ");
    scanf("%i", &mat2x);
    printf("Podaj wysokosc drugiej macierzy: ");
    scanf("%i", &mat2y);
    printf("Podaj ilosc watkow: ");
    scanf("%i", &threadsAmount);

    if(mat1x != mat2y){
        printf("Musisz podac odpowiednie macierze!");
        return;
    }

    struct ags* strAgs;

    int i;
    int j;
    for(i = 0; i < mat1y; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < mat1x; j++){
            strAgs->mat1[i][j] = random();
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < mat2y; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < mat2x; j++){
            strAgs->mat2[i][j] = random();
        }
    }


    for(j = 0; j < mat2x; j++){
        strAgs->semafor[j] = 0;
    }
    strAgs->rowsDone = mat2x;


    pthread_t threadsArray[threadsAmount];

    for(i = 0; i < threadsAmount; i++){
        if(pthread_create(&threadsArray[i], NULL, thread_multiply, (void*) strAgs)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;
        } 
    }

    for(i = 0; i < threadsAmount; i++){
        if(pthread_join(threadsArray[i], NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error joining thread\n");
        return 1;
        } 
    }
}

void *thread_multiply(void* ptr) {
    struct ags* agsStruct = (struct ags*) ptr;
    while(agsStruct->rowsDone > 0){
        printf("woho\n");
        agsStruct->rowsDone--;
    }
};
```

Ok here is code. Now the question. Im trying to make a program to multiply matrixes in threads. The problem is ive got error now when trying to run it. It compile fine, just when i enter 5 ints at the begginng it just crash, and i cant find why. Any idea how to repair it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allocating memory for your matrices. In your `struct ags` structure, you have two `long**` entries, but you never actually allocate the memory for them to use. You need to do so via dynamic memory allocation using `malloc` or `calloc`.

```
struct ags* strAgs;
```

Is wrong. You are creating a pointer, but not pointing it to any data. A quick workaround to reduce rewriting too much of your code would be:

```
struct ags actualStruct;
struct ags* strAgs = &actualStruct;
```

It seems like you're trying to do a multi-thread matrix multiplication application. I won't finish the multiplication logic since this looks to be homework, but I've included an updated version of your code below that compiles and runs fine on Linux, and handle the dynamically memory allocation and de-allocation/cleanup. [It also uses a constant `MAX_VALUE` to keep the matrix elements from suffering from integer overflow when your final program starts working.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Good luck!

**Code Listing**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_VALUE (10)

struct ags{
   long int **mat1;
   long int **mat2;
   int *semafor;
   int rowsDone;
};

void *thread_multiply(void*);

int main(int args, char** argv){
   int mat1x;
   int mat1y;
   int mat2x;
   int mat2y;
   int threadsAmount;

   printf("Podaj szerokosc pierwszej macierzy: ");
   scanf("%i", &mat1x);
   printf("Podaj wysokosc pierwszej macierzy: ");
   scanf("%i", &mat1y);
   printf("Podaj szerokosc drugiej macierzy: ");
   scanf("%i", &mat2x);
   printf("Podaj wysokosc drugiej macierzy: ");
   scanf("%i", &mat2y);
   printf("Podaj ilosc watkow: ");
   scanf("%i", &threadsAmount);

   if(mat1x != mat2y){
      printf("Musisz podac odpowiednie macierze!");
      return;
   }
   struct ags actualStruct = { 0 };
   struct ags* strAgs = &actualStruct;

   int i;
   int j;
   printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", mat1x, mat1y, mat2x, mat2y, threadsAmount);

   /* Dynamic memory allocation */
   int iErr = 0;
   if (!iErr) {
      if ((strAgs->mat1 = calloc(mat1y, sizeof(long int*))) == NULL) {
         printf("Memory allocation error!\n");
         iErr = 1;
      }
   }
   if (!iErr) {
      for (i=0; i<mat1y; i++) {
         if ((strAgs->mat1[i] = calloc(mat1x, sizeof(long int))) == NULL) {
            printf("Memory allocation error!\n");
            iErr = 1;
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   if (!iErr) {
      if ((strAgs->mat2 = calloc(mat2y, sizeof(long int*))) == NULL) {
         printf("Memory allocation error!\n");
         iErr = 1;
      }
   }
   if (!iErr) {
      for (i=0; i<mat2y; i++) {
         if ((strAgs->mat2[i] = calloc(mat2x, sizeof(long int))) == NULL) {
            printf("Memory allocation error!\n");
            iErr = 1;
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   if (!iErr) {
      if ((strAgs->semafor = calloc(mat2x, sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
         printf("Memory allocation error!\n");
         iErr = 1;
      }
   }

   /* Main logic */
   if (!iErr) {
      /* Populate the arrays */
      for(i = 0; i < mat1y; i++){
         for(j = 0; j < mat1x; j++){
            strAgs->mat1[i][j] = random() % MAX_VALUE;
         }
      }
      for(i = 0; i < mat2y; i++){
         for(j = 0; j < mat2x; j++){
            strAgs->mat2[i][j] = random() % MAX_VALUE;
         }
      }
      for(j = 0; j < mat2x; j++){
         strAgs->semafor[j] = 0;
      }
      strAgs->rowsDone = mat2x;

      /* Create group of worker threads to perform math operations */
      pthread_t threadsArray[threadsAmount];
      for(i = 0; i < threadsAmount; i++){
         if(pthread_create(&threadsArray[i], NULL, thread_multiply, (void*) strAgs)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
            return 1;
         }
      }

      /* Wait for all threads to complete before proceeding */
      for(i = 0; i < threadsAmount; i++){
         if(pthread_join(threadsArray[i], NULL)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error joining thread\n");
            return 1;
         }
      }

      /* Print out both matrices */
      printf("MATRIX 1:\n");
      for (i=0; i<mat1y; i++) {
         for (j=0; j<mat1x; j++) {
            printf("%02ld ", strAgs->mat1[i][j]);
         }
         printf("\n");
      }
      printf("MATRIX 2:\n");
      for (i=0; i<mat2y; i++) {
         for (j=0; j<mat2x; j++) {
            printf("%02ld ", strAgs->mat2[i][j]);
         }
         printf("\n");
      }
   }


   /* Clean up dynamically allocated memory */
   for (i=0; i<mat1y; i++) {
      free(strAgs->mat1[i]);
   }
   free(strAgs->mat1);

   for (i=0; i<mat2y; i++) {
      free(strAgs->mat2[i]);
   }
   free(strAgs->mat2);

   free(strAgs->semafor);

   /* Exit application */
   return 0;
}

void *thread_multiply(void* ptr) {
   struct ags* agsStruct = (struct ags*) ptr;
   while(agsStruct->rowsDone > 0){
      printf("woho\n");
      agsStruct->rowsDone--;
   }
};
```

Comment: Ahh. But i need it to be in size of mat1x mat1y etc.. Is it possible ?

Comment: @user3552292 Yes. I'll take a look in a bit.

Comment: Great,but i tried it alrdy. Still error. Program doesn't even print one printf after struct.

Comment: I was so close ! Great, thank u very much, good that u left logic for me because its really homework :) I'm using Java in everyday work so im not so familiar with these things, anyway good to learn smth new :)

Comment: @user3552292 Glad it helped. If you feel this answered your question, please also click the check mark next to the upvote/downvote button to the left of my post to mark it as the "Accepted" answer. :)

Comment: My great man, just one more issue. All is working fine, no errors, just why when i start this program 5 times ive got always the same values ? 0o 
http://pastebin.com/Pi6itEtf